# LibreOffice Writer: How to Replace Font of Searched Text

Tags: unicode, fonts, libreoffice

I have several documents in `.DOC` format that includes words in English and Sanskrit (Devanagari).  I am using LibreOffice Writer:

```
Version: 5.1.4.2
Build ID: 1:5.1.4-0ubuntu1
Locale: en-US (en_GB.UTF-8)
```

The default font is `Liberation Serif`, which I like and want to continue using, but some of the Sanskrit/Devanagari words do not display correctly.  There are some fonts that do display the Sanskrit/Devanagari words correctly, such as `Akshar Unicode`.  So, the words that do not display correctly, I change their font to `Akshar Unicode` by highlighting each individual, incorrect word and then changing the font from `Liberation Serif` to `Akshar Unicode`, which is a tedious and inefficient method.

**Is there a more efficient method to change the font of certain words?**

Here are two methods I've tried thus far, both of which do not seem to be able to change the font of the search results or the replacement text:

- Highlight the incorrect word and press `[CTRL] + [H]` to use the `Find & Replace` tool.
- Install the extension `Alternate searching 1.4.1`, which is a tool that is similar to `Find & Replace`, but more complex.

Ideally, the `Find & Replace` tool would be able to change the font of the search results or replacement text.

Answer (score 0):

The following macro selects the currently selected word everywhere in the document.  Then it sets the font.

```vb
Sub ChangeFontOfWords
    document   = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame
    dispatcher = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")
    oSels = ThisComponent.getCurrentSelection()
    oSel = oSels.getByIndex(0)

    dim args1(1) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
    args1(0).Name = "SearchItem.SearchString"
    args1(0).Value = oSel.getText()
    dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:ExecuteSearch", "", 0, args1())

    dim args2(0) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
    args2(0).Name = "CharFontName.FamilyName"
    args2(0).Value = "Akshar Unicode"
    dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:CharFontName", "", 0, args2())
End Sub
```

To use it, double-click a word to select it, then run the macro.  For convenience, go to `Tools -> Customize` and set up a hotkey or toolbar button to run the macro.